# How convert words with comma in object with value

Tags: javascript

I have:

> WAIT_FOR_ANALYSIS,EMAIL_SENT

and I need transform it to:

> `[{ value: 'WAIT_FOR_ANALYSIS' }, { value: 'EMAIL_SENT' }]`

I tried:

```js
const wordToArray = filtered.split(',');
console.log(Object.assign({}, wordToArray));
```

But returns:

> `{0: "WAIT_FOR_ANALYSIS", 1: "EMAIL_SENT"}`

Answer (score 3):

What your code does is splitting your input string, using comma as a delimiter (which would result in `['WAIT_FOR_ANALYSIS', 'EMAIL_SENT']`), after that you do `Object.assign({}, wordToArray)` which takes your array (which is essentially an object) and assigns key-value pairs (indexes and respective strings) to the empty object, giving you above result.

What you need to do instead is mapping your array (with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) into array of the same size where each string value is mapped into an object `{value: ..}`.

With slight trick of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it may look as follows:

```js
const str =`WAIT_FOR_ANALYSIS,EMAIL_SENT`,

      result = str.split(',').map(value => ({value}))
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Yevgen mentioned, you can map each token (following the split operation) to an object. Instead of creating objects with key/value pairs, you can use the [ECMAScript 2015 shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), as seen in his example.

When mapping to a object, if you simply pass-in the reference to another variable. A key will be created based on the name of the variable.

```js
const str = 'WAIT_FOR_ANALYSIS,EMAIL_SENT'

const arr = str.split(',').map(value => ({ value })) // { value: value }

console.log(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is an advanced solution, where an enum-like object is created.

```js
const str = 'WAIT_FOR_ANALYSIS,EMAIL_SENT'

const main = () => {
  const statusType = createEnum(str.split(/\s*,\s*/g))

  console.log(statusType)
}

const createEnum = (values) => values
  .reduce((res, name, ordinal) => ({
    ...res,
    [name]: { name, ordinal }
  }), {})
  
main()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```